# How to solve the following integral inequality $(\alpha+2)\cdot \int_0^1 x^\alpha(f(x)+f^{-1}(x)) \, dx \le 2$

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

Let $f:[0, 1]\to[0, 1]$ be continuous and bijective with $f(0) = 0$. Prove that for every $\alpha \ge 0$: $$(\alpha+2)\cdot \int_0^1 x^\alpha (f(x)+f^{-1}(x)) \, dx \le 2$$

To be fair I don't even know how to begin solving it. I'm pretty sure $f(0)=0$ should help me but I'm not sure how

Solution:
$f$ continuous and bijective with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)=1$$\implies$ $f$ is increasing
Using Young: $\int_0^x f(t) \, dt+\int_0^x f^{-1}(t) \, dt \ge x^2, x\in[0, 1]$ if and only if $f(x)=x$; so we can rewrite it as $\int_0^x (f(t)+f^{-1}(t)-2t) \, dt\ge 0, x\in[0, 1]$

Let $G:[0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $G(x)=\int_0^x (f(t)+f^{-1}(t)-2t) \, dt$. Then $G(1)=G(0)=0, G(x)\ge 0, x\in[0, 1]$

$G$ differentiable and for every $\alpha\ge 0$:

$$\int_0^1 x^{\alpha}(f(x)+f^{-1}(x)) \, dx = 2\int_0^1 x^{\alpha+1} \, dx + \int_0^1 x^\alpha(f(x)+f^{-1}(x)-2x) \, dx = \frac{2}{\alpha+2} + \int_0^1 x^\alpha G'(x)\,dx = \frac{2}{\alpha+2}+\lim_{a \to0} (G(1)-G(a)\cdot a^\alpha -\int_a^1 \alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1} G(x) \, dx) \le\frac{2}{\alpha+2}$$ therefore $$(\alpha+2)\cdot \int_0^1 x^\alpha (f(x)+f^{-1}(x)) \, dx \le 2$$

Comment: Is there a question about the "Solution" part edited in? If you found your own answer after posting the question, you can instead submit an answer to your own question.

Comment: I don't have any questions. Didn't think to answer my own question so I just edited it with the solution

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Hey where this problem comes from? I searched several real analysis problem books, didn't see such one.

Comment: Hi. It's from a contest in Romania for 7-12 grade. You can find it here: https://ssmr.ro/onm2021
Unfortunately there's no English translation but I can help if you want to

Comment: @LafaetTrafalet: You have almost all the ingredients. Integration by parts seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Phi(x)=\int^x_0(f+f^{-1})$. We have that $\Phi(x)\geq x^2$ and $\Phi(1)=1$. Integration by parts gives

$$\begin{align}
\int^1_0x^\alpha (f^(x)+f^{-1}(x))\,dx&= \Phi(x)x^\alpha\Big|^1_0-\alpha\int^1_0 x^{\alpha-1}\Phi(x)\,dx\\
&\leq 1-\alpha\int^1_0x^{\alpha+1}\,dx=1-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+2}=\frac{2}{\alpha+2}
\end{align}
$$

The conclusion follows.

Comment: Can you please explain me how $\phi(x) \ge x^2$?

Comment: @SufaidSaleel: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions)